# How to stop a Daemon Server in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am  running my rails application using the following

```
  $script/server -d webrick
```

on my Ubuntu system  , above command run the webrick server in background .  I could kill the process using  kill command

```
  $kill pid
```

Does rails provide any command to stop the background running daemon server ?

like the one provided by rails to start the server , Thanks .

**EDIT** When it is appropriate to start the daemon server ?  Any real time scenario will help Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about a rake task?

```
desc 'stop rails'
task :stop do
    pid_file = 'tmp/pids/server.pid'
    pid = File.read(pid_file).to_i
    Process.kill 9, pid
    File.delete pid_file
end
```

run with rake stop or sudo rake stop

Comment: Use `kill -9` only when the daemon hung. Otherwise you will lose your unflushed data from Active Directory caches.

Comment: That may be but you should only be running a server like that in development anyway.

Answer (score 87):

if it can be useful, on linux you can find which process is using a port (in this case 3000) you can use:

> lsof -i :3000

it'll return the pid too

Comment: Even on Mac/unix/bash...  Yep.  This is super helpful.  `lsof -i :3000` tells me the PID of the running ruby

Comment: `kill $(lsof -i :3000 -t)` - The **-t** option stands for **terse** which means it will just output the process ID.

Comment: awesome; here are my bash_aliases `alias stopRails='kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)'` with `alias startRails='rails server -d'` (will fail if you are not in your app directory, but thats okay) and finally `alias restartRails='stopRails && startRails'`

Comment: @Sudhi, your solution is totally awesome

Comment: Rubyfied version: `pid = \`lsof -i :3000 -t\`.chomp.to_i` (@Gerry really nice call on the `-t` flag, I learned something new today!)

Comment: Thank you for this. As a *nix noob, it is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 37):

Like Ryan said:

> the pid you want is in tmp/pids/

probably server.pid is the file you want.

You should be able to run `kill -9 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)` to bring down a daemonized server.

Comment: After `lsof -i :3000` I get the PID of ruby, then `kill -9 1406orWhateverThePIDofRubyWas` - easypeasy - Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, and lose the data that is in memory and not yet on disk.

Answer (score 19):

The only **proper** way to kill the Ruby on Rails default server (which is WEBrick) is:

```
kill -INT $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

If you are running Mongrel, this is sufficient:

```
kill $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

Use `kill -9` if your daemon hung. Remember the implications of `kill -9` - if the data kept in Active Record caches weren't flushed to disk, you will lose your data. (As I recently did)

Comment: Hmmm … but, as noted in another article, Rails or WEBrick or someone seems to be ignoring all the gentler signals.  I've been trying "kill -INT" then "kill -TERM" and then finally "kill -9," but the first two never work.          http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=terminate%20webrick%20rails%20server&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5891567%2Fcant-stop-webrick-1-3-1-with-ctrl-c-on-ubuntu-11-04&ei=q6TWT-WeBqTi2QX5zoW9Dw&usg=AFQjCNH94LjbNMEMT4xBiTHCKa72xhWQ-A&sig2=4cgBxEL6rG7JQFK8jkCOGQ

Answer (score 18):

The process id of the daemon server is stored in your application directory tmp/pids/. You can use your standard `kill process_id` with the information you find there.

Comment: Here's a one-liner that you can assign to an alias in your ~/.bashrc file: `kill -9 $(lsof -i:3000) &> /dev/null`. The part after `&>` is optional--it just suppresses some output from the kill command.

Comment: I'd recommend against running that because your browser might have port 3000 open since it's talking to your Rails server. I've accidentally killed Chrome a couple times this way. :)

Answer (score 18):

In your terminal to find out the process id (PID):

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then, use the number in the PID column to kill the process:

```
$ kill -9 <PID>
```

Answer (score 7):

[pguardiario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747618/265575) beat me to it, though his implementation is a bit dangerous since it uses `SIGKILL` instead of the (recommended) `SIGINT`. Here's a rake task I tend to import into my development projects:

**lib/tasks/stopserver.rake**

```
desc 'stop server'
task :stopserver do
  pid_file = 'tmp/pids/server.pid'
  if File.file?(pid_file)
    print "Shutting down WEBrick\n"
    pid = File.read(pid_file).to_i
    Process.kill "INT", pid
  end
  File.file?(pid_file) && File.delete(pid_file)
end
```

This issues an interrupt to the server if and only if the pidfile exists. It doesn't throw unsightly errors if the server isn't running, and it notifies you if it's actually shutting the server down.

If you notice that the server doesn't want to shut down using this task, add the following line after the `Process.kill "INT"` line, and try to upgrade to a kernel that has this bug fixed.

```
Process.kill "CONT", pid
```

*(Hat tip: [jackr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989852/265575))*

Answer (score 5):

A Ruby ticket, http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4777, suggests it's a kernel (Linux) bug. They give a work around (essentially equivalent to the Ctrl-C/Ctrl-Z one), for use if you've demonized the server:

1. kill -INT `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`
2. kill -CONT `cat tmp/pids/server.pid`

This seems to cause the original INT signal to be processed, possibly allowing data flush and so on.

Answer (score 5):

**Run this command:**

```
locate tmp/pids/server.pid
```

**output:**
Complete path of this file. Check your project directory name to find your concerned file if multiple files are shown in list.

Then run this command:

```
rm -rf [complete path of tmp/pids/server.pid file]
```

Comment: One-liner: `x=\`locate tmp/pids/server.pid\` && kill \`cat ${x}\``

Answer (score 4):

Here I leave a bash function which, if pasted in you `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` will alloy you do things like:

```
rails start # To start the server in development environment
rails start production # To start the server in production environment
rails stop # To stop the server
rails stop -9 # To stop the server sending -9 kill signal
rails restart # To restart the server in development environment
rails restart production # To restart the server in production environment
rails whatever # Will send the call to original rails command
```

Here it is the function:

```
function rails() {
  if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
     if [ "$2" = "" ]; then
        RENV="development"
     else
        RENV="$2"
     fi
     rails server -d -e "$RENV"
     return 0
  elif [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then
     if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
        kill $2 $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
        return 0
     else
        echo "It seems there is no server running or you are not in a rails project root directory"
        return 1
     fi
  elif [ "$1" = "restart" ]; then
     rails stop && rails start $2
  else
     command rails $@
  fi;
}
```

More information in the [blog post](http://waiting-for-dev.github.io/blog/2014/05/03/stop-and-restart-easily-a-rails-server/) I wrote about it.

Comment: do you have an equivalent batch file for this?

Comment: Nope, I'm sorry

Answer (score 3):

i don't think it does if you use -d. I'd just kill the process.

In the future, just open up another terminal window instead and use the command without -d, it provides some really useful debugging output.

If this is production, use something like passenger or thin, so that they're easy to stop the processes or restart the servers

Answer (score 3):

```
one-liner:  kill -INT `ps -e | grep ruby | awk '{print $1}'`
```

`ps -e` lists every process on the system

`grep ruby` searches that output for the ruby process

`awk` passes the first argument of that output 
(the pid) to `kill -INT`.

Try it with echo instead of kill if you just want to see the PID.

Answer (score 2):

if kill process not works, then
delete file server.pid from MyRailsApp/tmp/pids/

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I were trying to (unsuccesfully) stop with a normal kill, and thought I'd being doing something wrong.

A kill -9 is the only sure way to stop a ruby on rails server?
What!? Do you know the implications of this? Can be a disaster...

Comment: I just lost the data because of kill -9. The data was not yet flushed to SQLite, just in memory. Interesting fact, it was in the memory for a week.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

You can start your server in the background by adding `-d` to your command. For instance:

```
puma -d
```

To stop it, just kill whatever process is running on port 3000:

```
kill $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```