# How to restart Rails server programmatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, webserver

After the admin completes the setup process, I need to be able to restart the Rails server. Is it possible to do this while the server is running (he configures the setup in the Rails app)?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164091/how-to-stop-a-daemon-server-in-rails

Comment: Since you tagged this with 'nginx', try: sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

Comment: But how will Rails do a sudo command?